# NS_BINDING_ABORTED with svg images only

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, firefox

I have a simple JavaScript code that generating waiting load spinner when a captcha image refreshing. The script works fine with `gif` images but with animated `svg` images, the loading spinner does not work and in FireFox returns `NS_BINDING_ABORTED` in the browser's network console. Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#captchaImg").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        src = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
        width = '{{config('captcha.flat.width')}}px';
        height= '{{config('captcha.flat.height')}}px';
        console.log(width, height)
// IN THE FOLLOWING LINE, REPLACING gif with svg makes the error.
        $(this).children('img').attr({'src':'/imgs/loading.gif','width':width, 'height': height})
        src = src.replace(/&t=.*/,'')
        t = new Date();
        $(this).children('img').attr('src',src+"&t="+t.getTime());
        $( "#randQuote" ).text( '{{__('Loading')}}' );
        $.ajax({
                url: "/rand-quote",
                cache: false
             })
            .done(function( data ) {
               console.log(data.msg)
                $( "#randQuote" ).text( data.msg );
                return false;
            }); 
    })
})
```

I don't know what is the difference in this case between `gif` and `svg` that causes that issue? and how could I solve it?!

#### Note:

The svg image used is generated from https://loading.io and the following its code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="margin: auto; background: none; display: block; shape-rendering: auto;" width="64px" height="64px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
<g transform="rotate(0 50 50)">
  <rect x="37.5" y="5" rx="4.76" ry="4.76" width="25" height="34" fill="#482173">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.875s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(45 50 50)">
  <rect x="37.5" y="5" rx="4.76" ry="4.76" width="25" height="34" fill="#2e6f8e">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.75s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(90 50 50)">
  <rect x="37.5" y="5" rx="4.76" ry="4.76" width="25" height="34" fill="#29af7f">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.625s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(135 50 50)">
  <rect x="37.5" y="5" rx="4.76" ry="4.76" width="25" height="34" fill="#bddf26">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(180 50 50)">
  <rect x="37.5" y="5" rx="4.76" ry="4.76" width="25" height="34" fill="#482173">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.375s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(225 50 50)">
  <rect x="37.5" y="5" rx="4.76" ry="4.76" width="25" height="34" fill="#2e6f8e">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.25s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(270 50 50)">
  <rect x="37.5" y="5" rx="4.76" ry="4.76" width="25" height="34" fill="#29af7f">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.125s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(315 50 50)">
  <rect x="37.5" y="5" rx="4.76" ry="4.76" width="25" height="34" fill="#bddf26">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
  </rect>
</g>
<!-- [ldio] generated by https://loading.io/ --></svg>
```

Comment: What's your DNT (Do not track) setting? Does anything change if you change that setting?

Comment: @RobertLongson Please, take a look at the answer of mine.

Answer (score 0):

##### I found the solution but I still don't know the reason

The solution is simply adding the `loading.svg` in the HTML like the following:

```
<img style="display:none;" src="/imgs/loading.svg">
```

After that replacing `gif` by `svg` in the script has worked fine. The solution is inspired form my [Captcha Class](https://github.com/saidbakr/fox-captcha/blob/master/src/FoxCaptcha.php#L125) @ line 125. Originally, I made it to ensure loading the image during the page loading before its call from the JavaScript. I noticed that `svg` images works there fine.

> I still do not able to identify what is the difference between `gif`
> and `svg` that leads to that behavior, in which, adding the image
> `src` of the image into page's HTML is obligatory to allow calling it
> afterwords from the JavaScript?